# Is there a search option in Windows MS Office 2013 that lets you search for specific commands?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, if you press **Ctrl-Q** you can start typing a command name and it will show you what commands match, and how to find them.

In OSX, I believe this is called "spotlight" search.

Is there something similar, or an addon for Office?  It's maddening looking for a command you know exists, and then having to use Google just to find it.

Comment: What do you mean by "command" exactly (in the context of Office)?  Are you talking about while using the VBA editor?

Comment: Office context.  Like **EDIT** or  **DATA Fill Down**